# Optimize C# LINQ Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am working on a C# project and using SQL server 2008 R2 express as backend.

I have to find count of bookings where `BookingDate's Date component` is greater than a `tempDate`.

I wrote following code:

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1); //<= 5ms
var bookings = context.Bookings.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).ToList(); //<= 2ms
var count = bookings.Count(x => x.BookingDate.Date >= tempDate); //<= 2,534 ms
```

This code works and gives me correct count but its taking almost 3 seconds to execute (I found execution time using VS 2015). I want to optimize this code so that the execution time is reduced. Booking Table contains almost 20,000 records.

How do I minimize cost to compute?

Comment: The problem is most probably the call to ToList(), which selects everything to the client side.

Comment: @ba__friend: can you please suggest a workaround

Comment: ToList() is not needed to count the bookings, just remove it. EF will then only generate a SQL statement in the form of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM`..

Comment: You might also want an index on that date column.

Comment: Your timings look very wrong. The `count` line should almost be instantaneous given that it's all in memory by then. The `bookings` line should be the one that takes time. Can you please using `Stopwatch` to compute the times please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that my previous answer wasn't that good.
I did some test using a table with 10 000 entities and using .ToList() the time went from 280ms to 380ms. Also i found that selecting .Date doesn't work in linq queries so you have to do .ToList(). If you want to select count in the query you can't use DateTime.Date you have to use just DateTime.

2,500ms is quite slow. If you run your app in release mode it will probably be quite a bit faster.

---

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 4, 1); 
int count = context.Bookings.Count(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.BookingDate >= tempDate);
```

The problem is the .ToList() as it queries all the table rows instead of just the count

Comment: Visual Studio shows execution time in a different way. I have updated the code posted in question with the execution time. Also I need bookings list later in the code. I have posted only the part of code where execution cost is more

Comment: Maybe [TruncateTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596(v=vs.110).aspx) is worth a shot?

Comment: hey guys... thanks a lot... I removed the ToList() call and removed the .Date property from BookingDate as suggested. now its just taking 106ms. Thats a significant improvement...